# magento security update Patch Supee 5344 error

Tags: security, magento

I attempted to update magento with the Supee 5344 patch yesterday and got the following error when I ran the sh command.

```
127: not found

127: not found

0: not found
```

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...

```
patch: unrecognized option `--dry-run'

Usage: /usr/bin/patch [options] [origfile [patchfile]] [+ [options] 
[origfile]]...

Options:
       [-cCeEflnNRsStuv] [-b backup-ext] [-B backup-prefix] [-d directory]
       [-D symbol] [-F max-fuzz] [-i patchfile] [-o out-file] [-p[strip-count]]
       [-r rej-name] [-V {numbered,existing,simple}] [--check] [--context]
       [--prefix=backup-prefix] [--suffix=backup-ext] [--ifdef=symbol]
       [--directory=directory] [--ed] [--fuzz=max-fuzz] [--force] [--batch]
       [--ignore-whitespace] [--forward] [--reverse] [--output=out-file]
       [--strip[=strip-count]] [--normal] [--reject-file=rej-name] [--skip]
       [--remove-empty-files] [--quiet] [--silent] [--unified] [--version]
       [--version-control={numbered,existing,simple}] [--index-first]
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
```

Can anybody help me in figuring what I need to resolve this issue?  Is there a way to implement the patch manually?

Steve

Comment: your version of patch isn't whatever version the developer used... not much you can do, short of getting them to fix their script.

Comment: It is the same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720435/magento-supee-1533-5344-127-not-found-when-patching

Answer (score 3):

heres a link to check for the Shoplift bug https://shoplift.byte.nl/

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that the patch you are applying is the correct patch for the version of your Magento.

The easiest way to find out what version of Magento you are using is to login as admin and it will tell you in the footer. Once you have this version go to the Magento downloads page and find the right patch file for the right version of magento.

Answer (score 0):

According to the output the patch binary on your system have no --dry-run option (looks like some BSD OS is installed there, not linux). Your patch binary though seems provides --check option instead, so you can use it instead of --dry-run by editing PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh file and replacing --dry-run option with --check.

Another option can be to not use patch at all and just upload all patched files from http://magentary.com/kb/apply-supee-5344-and-supee-1533-without-ssh/

To verify that patch was installed successfully you can use https://shoplift.byte.nl/ service.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the exact same error the other day - what fixed it for me was moving an executing the patch in the correct directory (depending on how your Magento site is set up.

Initially, I was trying to run it out out of `/var/www/site-name` - it needs to be in `/var/www/site-name/magento`.

There are other troubleshooting steps here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#trouble