# Magento SUPEE-1533 5344 127: not found when patching

Tags: magento, patch

I'm having the following issue with the recent patches.

Magento CE Version 1.9.0.1

---

usr/home/******/public_html/****** > sh PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh

127: not found
127: not found
0: not found

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...

---

/usr/home/******/public_html/****** > sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh

127: not found
127: not found
0: not found

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...

patch: unrecognized option `--dry-run'
Usage: /usr/bin/patch [options] [origfile [patchfile]] [+ [options] [origfile]]...

Options:

```
   [-cCeEflnNRsStuv] [-b backup-ext] [-B backup-prefix] [-d directory]

   [-D symbol] [-F max-fuzz] [-i patchfile] [-o out-file] [-p[strip-count]]

   [-r rej-name] [-V {numbered,existing,simple}] [--check] [--context]

   [--prefix=backup-prefix] [--suffix=backup-ext] [--ifdef=symbol]

   [--directory=directory] [--ed] [--fuzz=max-fuzz] [--force] [--batch]

   [--ignore-whitespace] [--forward] [--reverse] [--output=out-file]

   [--strip[=strip-count]] [--normal] [--reject-file=rej-name] [--skip]

   [--remove-empty-files] [--quiet] [--silent] [--unified] [--version]

   [--version-control={numbered,existing,simple}] [--index-first]
```

ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious here. If not can someone link to an article on manually applying the patches if such an article exists. I did have to manually remove the cache to get back into the back-end after this so I'm not sure if the patch did something.

As always thank you for the help

-Eric

Comment: More appropriate for magento.stackexchange as it is a Magento administration problem for a security patch, not an actual programming question.

Answer (score 2):

According to the output the `patch` binary on your system have no `--dry-run` option (looks like some BSD OS is installed there, not linux). Your `patch` binary though seems provides `--check` option instead, so you can use it instead of `--dry-run` by editing `PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh` file and replacing `--dry-run` option with `--check`.

Another option can be to not use patch at all and just upload all patched files from http://magentary.com/kb/apply-supee-5344-and-supee-1533-without-ssh/

Answer (score 1):

the patch you are applying is /usr/home/******/public_html/****** > sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh

EE version 1.13 later i go to https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/ and check for 1533 patch and i am try to download the CE 1.8.X to 1.9.X

https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/downloadFile/file_id/517/file_category/210/store_id/1

so may be possible your files is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The patch you want to install is for Magento Enterprise Edition v1.13. It is not possible to install it on CE.

Comment: This is not true, whilst Magento haven't been very clear with the naming convention of their patch files, SUPEE-1533 still needs to be applied to Magento CE as well which Magento confirm [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/appsec-900_addhandler.html#patch).